# La Inquisición le quemó por brujo - why "le" instead of "lo"?

Tags: pronombres

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series Ministerio del Tiempo:

> La Inquisición le quemó por brujo.

Context: The subsecretary of the Ministry of Time, a Spanish ministry assigned to prevent changes of the past, is explaining the origins of the time travel infrastructure that they use: in order to prevent being expelled from his country, a Jewish rabbi revealed the network of doors which connect the present with past periods to the catholic kings in the Medieval period. The kings gave the rabbi to the Inquisition, which burned him as a witch.

As the object pronoun in the sentence refers to the rabbi and "quemar" is a direct transitive verb (i.e. it requires a direct object"), shouldn't the direct object pronoun "lo" be used instead of the indirect object pronoun "le" ?

Comment: "le" is also a direct object pronoun — considered fully valid for animate masculine references and/or polite references of either generate.

Comment: I have never seen "le" being used as a direct object pronoun. Could you please provide a reference that backs it up?

Comment: https://dle.rae.es/?w=le "U. t. c. acus. m. sing. referido a personas. Síguele.", "U. t. c. acus. Les llevaré donde ustedes quieran."